# How to decrease size of window's buttons section in extjs4

Tags: extjs4

I am working in extjs4. I have view as=[image]

I have code for this as=

```
Ext.create('widget.window',{
            bodyPadding : 15,
            modal: true,
            closeAction: 'destroy',
            resizable:false,
            width : 400,
            height : 200,
            config: {
                record:''
            },
            items: [{ 
                    xtype: 'boxselect',
                    height: 30,
                    itemId: 'copy-to-compaign',
                    queryMode: 'local',
                    store:store,
                    width: 250,
                    displayField: 'name',
                    valueField: 'id',
                    value: '',
                    multiSelect: true
            }],
            buttons:[
                {
                 xtype : 'linkbutton',
                 margin:'50 10 10 10',

            },{
                 cls:'addBtnIcon',
                 padding:'10 10 10 10',
                 height: 50,
                 width: 90,

            ]
        });
```

i want to decrease size of bottom buttons section. So how to do it in extjs4

Answer (score 0):

U cannot decrease the size of that section, but u can change the padding and margin properties to reduce the extra space to the borders.

Padding and margin properties are composed of 4 items: [north] [east] [south] [west].

For example, u can change the **bodyPadding** property of the window to **5**, the margin property of **linkButton** to **'50 10 0 0'** and the padding property of the **add Button** to **'0 0 0 10'**, think will decrease the size.

Hope will help.